# Moodle: Exception - Call to undefined method theme_boost\output\core_renderer::get_setting()

Tags: exception, moodle, moodle-theme

After Installing the moodle website(Moodle Version: 3.8.1), on opening the login page(/login/index.php). I am getting below error.

```
Exception - Call to undefined method theme_boost\output\core_renderer::get_setting()
```

Please let me know what are the changes require.. in framework or in configurations

Comment: Can you switch on debugging to developer mode, then copy and paste the result in your question. Also the version of Moodle you are using. https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Debugging#Enabling_debugging

Comment: @RussellEngland Getting same result , not any additional info while turning on developer debugging mode. Moodle Version: 3.8.1

Comment: You might need to switch on "Display debug messages" too, so they are displayed in the browser

Comment: @RussellEngland Switched on that too.. but no difference.. anyways i got it resolved by clearing moodledata folder.. thanks